# How to debug why I am not getting the right output from a C# program?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# but I have learned Java for a year and I found C# almost similar. I am trying to make a program where the output is like this

```
My 
My Name
My Name Is
My Name Is Ahan
```

and the program I have written is this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str1 = "My Name Is Ahan";
        int i = 0 , length = str1.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(length);

        for(; i<length; i++ )
        {
            char ch = str1[i];

            if (ch == ' ')
            {
                int catchnum = str1.IndexOf(ch);

                string displayValue = str1.Substring(0, catchnum);
                Console.WriteLine(displayValue);
            }
            else;

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but my guess is you can replace much of your `for` and `IndexOf` logic with a simple call to [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Well what *is* your output?

Comment: Why dont you just debug your code? (cpt.obvious)

Comment: You haven't shown us the output you're getting. That's basic information you need to include in the question. You also likely haven't debugged your application. In trivial code like this, you can most likely solve it yourself with some time in the debugger. [Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) to learn how.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1 = "My Name Is Ahan";
    string[] words = str1.Split(' ');

    for (int i=0;i<words.Length;i++)
    {
        var selectedWords = words.Take(i + 1);
        Console.Write($"{string.Join(" ", selectedWords)} ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
int catchnum = str1.IndexOf(ch);
```

Within the loop you're always finding the index of the *first* space. You already *have* the index of the *current* space when you find it, so you could just do:

```
if (ch == ' ')
{
    string displayValue = str1.Substring(0, i);
    Console.WriteLine(displayValue);
}
```

I would also note that C# and Java are extremely similar for these basic operations - the same code would behave identically in Java with only minor syntax differences. Certainly the code could be simpler by using some basic library functions (like `string.Split` and Linq) that *would* be different between the two platforms, but that's not the issue here.

In other words, your errors aren't due to translation between Java and C# - they're basic logic errors that would have manifested in any programming language.